# Android Studio application crashes when trying to use an ArrayList from checkboxes to display on another activity's listview

Tags: android

I'm making a food ordering application with checkboxes to select certain food items. I'm having trouble with putting the items into an ArrayList and displaying them onto the confirmation page.

My first activity with my attempt at making an ArrayList out of checkboxes:

```
public class Appetizers extends AppCompatActivity {


private static ArrayList<String> selectionApp = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<Double> selectionAppTotal = new ArrayList<Double>();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_appetizers);


    Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAppetizers);

    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Appetizers.this, Menu.class));
            finish();
        }
    });
}



public void selectItem (View view)
{
    boolean checked = ( (CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.checkBox_app1:

            if(checked)
            {
                selectionApp.add("Spring Rolls");

                selectionAppTotal.add(3.50);
            }

            else
            {
                selectionApp.remove("Spring Rolls");
                selectionAppTotal.remove(3.50);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.checkBox_app2:

            if(checked)
            {
                selectionApp.add("Dumplings");
                selectionAppTotal.add(7.95);
            }

            else
            {
                selectionApp.remove("Dumplings");
                selectionAppTotal.remove(7.95);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.checkBox_app3:

            if(checked)
            {
                selectionApp.add("Potstickers");
                selectionAppTotal.add(7.95);
            }

            else
            {
                selectionApp.remove("Potstickers");
                selectionAppTotal.remove(7.95);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.checkBox_app4:

            if(checked)
            {
                selectionApp.add("Egg Rolls");
                selectionAppTotal.add(8.25);
            }

            else
            {
                selectionApp.remove("Egg Rolls");
                selectionAppTotal.remove(8.25);
            }
            break;

        case R.id.checkBox_app5:

            if(checked)
            {
                selectionApp.add("Deep Fried Wonton");
                selectionAppTotal.add(7.95);
            }

            else
            {
                selectionApp.remove("Deep Fried Wonton");
                selectionAppTotal.remove(7.95);
            }
            break;
    }

}



public void setSelection(ArrayList<String> selection) {
    this.selectionApp = selection;
}

public static ArrayList<String> getSelection() {
    return selectionApp;
} }
```

The activity that I'm trying to insert the ArrayList onto the ListView on:

```
public class ConfirmationPage extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList totalList = null;
ListView orderList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirmation_page);

    totalList = Appetizers.getSelection();

    orderList = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ConfirmationPage.this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, totalList);

    orderList.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}

After selecting checkboxes and then moving onto the Confirmation Page with the ListView, the application immediately crashes.

Crash error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID
>   to be a TextView
>           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:445)
>           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:415)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2366)
>           at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2052)
>           at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:786)
>           at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:847)
>           at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1826)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2165)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:753)
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2792)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
>           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:432)
>           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:415) 
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2366) 
>           at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2052) 
>           at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:786) 
>           at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:847) 
>           at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1826) 
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2165) 
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672) 
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194) 
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1083) 
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672) 
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194) 
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323) 
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261) 
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672) 
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194) 
>           at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444) 
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672) 
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194) 
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323) 
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261) 
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672) 
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194) 
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812) 
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656) 
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565) 
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672) 
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194) 
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323) 
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261) 
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:753) 
>           at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672) 
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194) 
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2792) 
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2319) 
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460) 
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183) 
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949) 
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761) 
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696) 
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935) 
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pasting the exact error message you get from the logcat (tab at the bottom of Android Studio) will help people diagnose your issue much more quickly than if they have to read through a lot of your code.

Comment: Show your Crash Error..

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't really sure how to post it properly..

Comment: see the error, `ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID ` and the layout you have assigned while creating arrayadapter is not a textview.

Comment: Oh! I got it working. Figured out it was the resource I used for the ArrayAdapter